# Call asmx web service from Windows Azure Scheduler

Tags: web-services, azure, asmx, azure-scheduler

I have an asmx web service running in a Web Role in a Windows Azure cloud application.  I want to user the Windows Azure scheduler to call this service on an hourly basis.  I am able to create the job but everything I have tried in the URI results in an error.

I can call the same web service successfully from a web page using ajax using a URI such as :
http://www.example.com/myservice.asmx/TheFunction

but this form returns an error (when I use either a GET or  a POST):
Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/TheFunction'.

Can anyone advise what format this URI should take?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help, but our team found that if you're using the brand new Management screens from the Azure Portal to do this, you can only set the URL and the Content, but you don't appear to have access to the request headers.

We were calling into an MVC application, and found that we need to add a header variable (Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded) in order for our Router / Controllers to pull the associated POST arguments.  We're looking at using the API to create the job instead, as there appears to be control over the headers using this method.

See the "headers" argument within the 
[Create Job Method in the Scheduler API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn528937.aspx).